# How to find Operation TIme of an Algoritm?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I am learning how to find operation time of algorithm, but in this pic i dont get what is meant by 1 + 2n + 2(n-1).
and from where these equations came from

[image]

Comment: You would need to have a look at some earlier content which the community can't have clarity about.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni, I'm pretty sure that there's enough information in the slide. =)

Comment: @elliott How is first for loop `1+2n+2(n-1)`? May be I would re-read the answer but I didn't get it from the first glance at the answer.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni basically the author must have made a mistake. I explain the mistake at the end of "Line 1: section. =)

Comment: @Elliott One needs to wait for OP to bring clarity to the post. If we assume something and answer, the answer might need an update later. In such cases, neither the post by OP remains useful for the community nor the answers if someone tries to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the person who wrote those slides thought that it was a good idea to try to be more "accurate", even though they're weren't being accurate (and it's probably a bad idea to try).

### Line 1

```c
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
```

`i = 0` only executed once (we don't keep initialising `i`). So this counts as:

> 1

`i < n-1` executed before the loop starts, between every iteration, and after the last iteration (that's how it knows how to exit). So this counts as:

> number of iterations + 1
> = num_elements{0, ..., n-2} + 1
> = (n-1) + 1
> = n

`i++` executed after every iteration (not during the first iteration this time). So this counts as:

> number of iterations
> = n - 1

All up:

> (1) + (n) + (n-1)

Now, this isn't the same as what's on your lecture slides, because your lecturer has decided that:
`i < n-1`
*really* is:
`int tmp_max = n - 1; i < tmp_max;`

So they think it's really two operations, even though the compiler will pre-compute this value only once (before the loop). It also unnecessarily confuses things for people like you who are students.

They must also think that:
`i++`
*really* is
`i = i + 1`
or, in other words:
`int tmp_i = i + 1; i = tmp_i`

Again, they're misunderstanding how c/c++ compilers work. `i++` is nowadays always equivalent to `++i`, which doesn't use any temporary values, and hence occurs in only a single clock cycle.

Confused? When you're studying complexity theory you're not supposed to care about this stuff. A single addition takes only one clock cycle, but division takes about 5 on most modern CPUs, but I doubt that your teacher expects you to consider *that*. When you're studying complexity you aren't supposed to be studying the processor. The whole point of complexity theory is that you don't care about these multiplicative constants.

What we care about is that `i` goes from `0` to `n` (who cares about the `n-1`), and that the complexity of this line is:

> O(n).

### Line 2

```c
for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
```

Here there's the same poor reasoning in their decision of multiplicative constants, this time each `j < n-i-1` is considered 3 operations by your teacher.

As for the inner part, this makes sense, except that the author has failed to separate the problem.

We should instead *first* calculate the complexity of this line as if `i` is a constant:

> 1 + (n-i) + (n-i)
> = O(n-i)

And later remember that `j` values will go from `0` to `n-i`.

### Lines remaining

These are constant time. No matter the values of `n`, `i` or `j`, the program can either execute only the `if` statement, or it can execute all 4 lines.

> O(1)

### All together:

> Outer loop, i = {0, ..., n}, O(n)
> inner loop, j = {0, ..., n - i}, O(n-i)
> inside loop, O(1)

Let's remove our modularity and recognise that `i` isn't a constant:

> complexity of the two loops = O(n-0) + O(n-1) + ... + O(0)
> = O(1 + 2 + 3 ... + n)
> = O(n(n+1)/2)
> = O(n^2)

I'm guessing that you already know [how to find the sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/34400/539148) of:

> 1 + 2 + 3 ... + n

So how many times is the inner loop executed? as many times as the iterations of the second loop - as the complexity of its contents are independent of the complexity of the loop, we can just multiply:

> overall complexity = O(n^2) * O(1)
> = O(n^2)

---

I hope my explanation of modularising the calculation helps. It's very useful for larger examples - especially real code bases. Most of the time you don't have the dependencies between the modular components, so you can just add or multiply the components - Hopefully I've shown that modularity is still useful even when you have dependencies.